# Why can't I use STAThread attribute in C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I wan to use the STAThread attribute on my the main thread of my program. However, Visual Studio says it cannot find it. I have tried references necessary assemblies and using proper namespace, but it just can't find it.

Edit:

I have been able to get to work successfully after manually creating a thread with the 
ApartmentState to STA. I think this is the equivalent to setting the thread, be it the main thread, but not exactly because i'm creating another thread. Anyone have another way to do this.

Here is the code:

```
void threadStart ()
{
    Application::Run (gcnew GraphicsForm());
}
[System::STAThread] // This will not work!
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Thread ^t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart (threadStart));
    t->ApartmentState = ApartmentState::STA;
    t->Start();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: CTRL+F `STAThread` http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/06/07/ccliwpf/

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It's an unfound identifier message, something to the extent of "STAThread attribute not found."

Comment: Do you have a reference to `mscorlib` in your project?

Comment: Yeah, its checkbox in the reference editor is checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I create a new C++/CLI project in Visual Studio 2012 with only a single `main()` function and then add `[System::STAThread]` in front of `main()`, it compiles and runs without a problem. To me, this means that it is most likely a settings difference between projects.

My recommendation is to do the same thing. Create a new C++/CLI project, add `[System::STAThread]` and see if it has any issues. If not, then you're at the point of checking the differences between the two projects to determine why one works properly and the other is giving you an error.

Comment: Yeah, when I start with a clean project, mine works too. However, I do not know where to start when comparing the projects. Should I look at the properties of each?

Comment: Yes, check the properties and the references. Can also open the project files and have a look. Not sure where the difference will be.

Comment: Okay, i'll do that. Probably going to be many differences. Got to find which one the problem is. Thank you.